# Mercurial: "no match found" when performing merge, "no node!" if I try to strip

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have a mercurial dropbox hosted in a Dropbox folder on which I push from another repo that I keep in my office PC. In this way I can work on my project from the office and perform hotfixes from home.

Something bad happened while synchronizing, therefore a file wasn't correctly put in sync somewhere. I have a revision (n. 678) which I can't merge with actual head.

[image]

If I try to merge I get this message

> abort:
> data/hotelsclick/src/main/res/values/string-array.xml.i@5f2b6faa86a1:
> no match found!

if I try to delete that useless revision with *hg strip 678* I get

> abort:
> data/hotelsclick/src/main/res/values/string-array.xml.i@5f2b6faa86a1:
> no node!

and if I perform a *hg verify* this is the result

> ```
> checking files  [...]/src/main/res/values/string-array.xml@678: 5f2b6faa86a1 in manifests not found
> ```
>
> libs/date-interval-picker/.git/index@678: a83e1b77d446 in manifests
> not found 8009 files, 681 changesets, 14161 total revisions 2
> integrity errors encountered! (first damaged changeset appears to be
> 678)

what if I try to push?

> searching for changes
> abort: push creates new remote head 16c4912af9a5!
> (merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)

So I cannot merge, cannot delete that revision, cannot push. I'm pretty stuck and I don't know why. Can anybody please help? I don't care about the content of revision 678, if I could I'd delete it happily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend against using a file synchronization service (whether Dropbox or Google Drive or something else) for use with version control systems. These services do not respect the atomicity of repository operations; even version control systems with single file repositories (such as Fossil) are not 100% safe and even if only a single user is using the service.

Second, you have a partially corrupted repository that you need to repair. In the ideal case, you have a clean backup somewhere, even if it's not perfectly up-to-date and can replay the missing revisions selectively (e.g. with `hg export` and `hg import`).

Barring that, the next step would be to see if you can do a partial clone. For example, you can try:

```
hg clone -r 680 /path/to/repo /path/to/clean_repo
```

This should normally skip revision 678, if only that data is defective. However, the way that delta compression works, revisions that occur in order after 678 may also have been corrupted. In this case, I would try it with `-r 677` instead of `-r 680` and see if `hg export` works for copying revisions `679` and `680`.

If that does not work and the corruption goes deeper, I would then try the convert extension:

```
hg --config extensions.convert= convert --config convert.hg.ignoreerrors=True /path/to/repo /path/to/clean_repo
```

Note that such a conversion will likely change the hash values of individual repository entries and means that you will have to update the repository contents everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, I cloned the repo from /old_repo to /old_repo_new and then cloned it back to /old_repo. The broken commit was not cloned at al!

Thank you so much!

P.S. I've been using mercurial on dropbox for one year by now, never had issues before. Since I'm the only one who writes code on this project I really rarely need to merge, so it's been a perfect solution so far :-) The important thing to remember is that you should suspend sync when you start working and sync everything in bulk once you've finished.